# Align two div no matter what

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want my two divs to be aligned no matter what (the bottom two), because sometime in the left div, a picture can be inside with different size, and in the right one there is a textarea, with different size text too... I did a small trick where I put a min-heigth on both but I feel like it's wrong.
I did this on JSFiddle so you can see :

https://jsfiddle.net/532cmwLb/

Here's my original code :

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-light border clearfix" role="alert">
        Modification de la photo - Taille de l'image : 592 * 398 pixels
    </div>

    <div class="bg-white border p-4 justify-content-center text-center">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="text-center" style="max-width:300px">

                    <?php $thumb = (!empty($biopic)) ? $biopic : 'https://via.placeholder.com/880x300&amp;text=592x398'; ?>
                    <a href="<?=$thumb;?>" id="biopic_preview" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="biography" data-type="image">
                        <img src="<?=$thumb;?>" class="img-fluid" title="biopic">
                    </a>

                    <button type="button" name="biopic_preview" id="biopic_preview" class="btn btn-outline-first btn-sm awmedias mt-3" data-width="398" data-height="592">
                        <i class="far fa-image fa-fw"></i> Choisir un fichier
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="biopic_post" value="biopic_post" class="btn btn-first btn-sm mt-3">Valider</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="alert alert-light mt-4 mt-md-0 border clearfix" role="alert">
        Modification du texte de présentation - Longueur comprise entre 100 et 1000 caractères
    </div>

    <div class="bg-white border p-4 justify-content-center text-center" style="min-height:590px !important;">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

                <?php $myText = $bioText ?? ''?>
                <textarea name="bio_text" id="bio_text" cols="50" rows="18"><?=$myText?></textarea>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="text_post" class="btn btn-first btn-sm mt-3">Valider</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---------- Correction i used ----------

```
<div class="container-fluid pt-3 pb-3">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-1 mb-3">

      <div class="alert alert-light border h-100" role="alert">
        Modification de la photo - Taille de l'image : 592 * 398 pixels
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-3 mb-3">

      <div class="bg-white border p-4 justify-content-center text-center h-100">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="text-center" style="max-width:300px">

              <a href="#" id="biopic_preview" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="biography" data-type="image">
                <img src="somePIC" class="img-fluid" title="biopic">
              </a>

              <button type="button" name="biopic_preview" id="biopic_preview_btn" class="btn btn-outline-first btn-sm awmedias mt-3" data-width="398">
                    <i class="far fa-image fa-fw"></i> Choisir un fichier
                  </button>

            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="biopic_post" value="biopic_post" class="btn btn-first btn-sm mt-3">Valider</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-2 mb-3">

      <div class="alert alert-light border h-100" role="alert">
        Modification du texte de présentation - Longueur comprise entre 100 et 1000 caractères
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 order-sm-4 mb-3">

      <div class="bg-white border p-4 justify-content-center text-center h-100" style="min-height:590px !important;">
        <form method="post">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

            <textarea name="bio_text" id="bio_text" cols="50" rows="18">SOME TEXT</textarea>

          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="text_post" class="btn btn-first btn-sm mt-3">Valider</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

(I use HTML5, with Bootstrap 4)

Comment: Create two separate rows.

Comment: @m4n0 i'm assuming from their code that in mobile the current columns should appear stacked in the same layout, putting them into rows will break this.

Comment: Yes that's what I've tried but as @joshmoto said, when i do this this isn't responsive anymore because it won't stack correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how dynamic your (this) row layout is, you could wrap each element in a column class within this row layout. Which makes each column div equal heights in the current flex row.

Your supplied code layout default order is as follows...

1. `alert 1` by default `order-1`
2. `biopic_post` by default `order-2`
3. `alert 2` by default `order-3`
4. `text_post` by default `order-4`

Which by default will look like this example below when you wrap each one in a column class...

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/qw7eto3j/

```html
<div class="container-fluid pt-3 pb-3">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-6 mb-3">

      <div class="alert alert-light border h-100" role="alert">
        Modification de la photo - Taille de l'image : 592 * 398 pixels
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-6 mb-3">

      <div class="bg-white border p-4 justify-content-center text-center h-100">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="text-center" style="max-width:300px">

              <a href="#" id="biopic_preview" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="biography" data-type="image">
                <img src="somePIC" class="img-fluid" title="biopic">
              </a>

              <button type="button" name="biopic_preview" id="biopic_preview_btn" class="btn btn-outline-first btn-sm awmedias mt-3" data-width="398">
                    <i class="far fa-image fa-fw"></i> Choisir un fichier
                  </button>

            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="biopic_post" value="biopic_post" class="btn btn-first btn-sm mt-3">Valider</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-6 mb-3">

      <div class="alert alert-light border h-100" role="alert">
        Modification du texte de présentation - Longueur comprise entre 100 et 1000 caractères
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-6 mb-3">

      <div class="bg-white border p-4 justify-content-center text-center h-100" style="min-height:590px !important;">
        <form method="post">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

            <textarea name="bio_text" id="bio_text" cols="50" rows="18">SOME TEXT</textarea>

          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="text_post" class="btn btn-first btn-sm mt-3">Valider</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

---

But here is the cool bit you can use bootstrap `order` classes re-arrange these divs inside the current row.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#reordering

So in this example below I've re-ordered the column divs to this structure...

1. `alert 1` is now set to `.order-sm-1`
2. `biopic_post` is now set to `.order-sm-3`
3. `alert 2` is now set to `.order-sm-2`
4. `text_post` is now set to `.order-sm-4`

So when in screen size `sm` and above, these orders will be used.

In this demo below i've removed `-sm` from all `.col-` and `.order-` classes so the ordering and column sizes will work in stackoverflow live demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/eja0g4kh/1/

```html
<div class="container-fluid pt-3 pb-3">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-6 order-1 mb-3">

      <div class="alert alert-light border h-100" role="alert">
        Modification de la photo - Taille de l'image : 592 * 398 pixels
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-6 order-3 mb-3">

      <div class="bg-white border p-4 justify-content-center text-center h-100">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="text-center" style="max-width:300px">

              <a href="#" id="biopic_preview" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="biography" data-type="image">
                <img src="somePIC" class="img-fluid" title="biopic">
              </a>

              <button type="button" name="biopic_preview" id="biopic_preview_btn" class="btn btn-outline-first btn-sm awmedias mt-3" data-width="398">
                    <i class="far fa-image fa-fw"></i> Choisir un fichier
                  </button>

            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="biopic_post" value="biopic_post" class="btn btn-first btn-sm mt-3">Valider</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-6 order-2 mb-3">

      <div class="alert alert-light border h-100" role="alert">
        Modification du texte de présentation - Longueur comprise entre 100 et 1000 caractères
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-6 order-4 mb-3">

      <div class="bg-white border p-4 justify-content-center text-center h-100" style="min-height:590px !important;">
        <form method="post">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

            <textarea name="bio_text" id="bio_text" cols="50" rows="18">SOME TEXT</textarea>

          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="text_post" class="btn btn-first btn-sm mt-3">Valider</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Here is a fiddle with your original responsive breakpoint classes with the same applied on ordering classes.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/6zpu93tn/

Test this responsively to see the change from `xs` to `sm` window width.

Comment: Thank you very much, good explanation, clear and everything.

If i understood, with the 2nd exemple, the difference between my breakpoint and this is how it stack right? Instead of being stack on one another, the two blocks (counting the small block and the one beneath as one) stay next to each other?

Thank you again for you time, you've been really helpful.

Comment: Yeah flex basically throws previous understanding of floating block elements out the window, it's pretty magical in comparison. If you want older IE compatibility it don't fair to well, IE10+ is supported... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/browsers-devices/ - who cares about the older IE's tho :-)

Comment: @Shogu23 sorry i didn't read your reply right, your order of you key html elements natively reads from top to bottom, my inclusion of the bootstrap order classes simply re-orders them, based on bootstraps responsive breakpoints. I wrapped each of your key elements in a bootstrap column class within a single (your) row, which handles the flex row height. It is a funny one to get your head around but `bootstraps 4` columns use flex, so any bootstrap `col` on the same `flex-row`... are equal height.